# display coordinates over the image

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code which will output the coordinates in the gui present anywhwere when double Clicked.

Problem:I wanted an background image,if i wanted to know the coordinates over the background image ,even after double click i am not getting the result.

My code:

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
def clicked(event):
    print "The user clicked at coordinates", event.x, event.y
root.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
image = tki.PhotoImage(file='linux.gif')
image1 = Tkinter.Label(root, image=image).grid() 

root.mainloop()
```

PLs help me on how to output the coordinates,even present over the image.

Comment: Seems like you edited your question which makes the answer below kind of useless. Please revert it back to original version. By the way, your edited version should work if you have `linux.gif` in your relative path.

Comment: yes now my code is working.but i asked this questionle as an examp for this original question.here its not working in the above specified manner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573665/display-rows-and-column-but-not-working-over-image-in-tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you c/p some lines from different codes and since you did that that, you need to fix those code pieces to work as one.

First answer these questions. After that, it should be easy to implement them in your code.

- Which [event format](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) do you need to get double clicks?
- In what purpose you used `tki` prefix?
- What does `self.` do in a python code? When to use it etc..?
- What happens when you have two variables which have same name?

Comment: What is "c/p"? Copy/paste?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes. I meant copy/paste by c/p.